# css - organisation chart - vertical line is not fitting in some scenario

Tags: html, css

I am using the following plugin. 
https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart.

In some resolution, the vertical line is not fitting properly.
https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart/issues/410

I have analysed the rendered html and tried with the same code. 
I am getting the same issue for some resolutions.

Please see the following fiddler.

```css
.downline{
  height:30px;
  width:2px;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
  background: red;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(217, 83, 79, 0.8);
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 55px;
    width: 2px;
    float: none;
}


.leftLine{
  border-right:1px solid green;
}
.rightLine{
  border-left:1px solid green;
}
table{
 margin:50px;
     border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
}

.item{
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div class="downline">
    
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="leftLine">
 &nbsp;
 </td>
 <td class="rightLine">
   &nbsp;
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" >
   <div class="item">
   Test 123
   
   </div>
 </td>
 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can add `width: 50%` to `.leftLine` and `.rightLine`, but that causes `.item` to wrap the text content

Comment: But there is a glitch in the edges.